# save HTML response into a varible in WSO2 Micro Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have created an API which return HTLM response , i would like to save the response data into a property in WSO2 Integration Studio .
I used this configuration but it didn't work.

```
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/currentsession">       
 <inSequence>                
    <call>         
       <endpoint>                   
 <http method="get" uri-template="http://**************************">    
                    <suspendOnFailure>         
                   <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>                         
   <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>                       
     <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>                      
  </suspendOnFailure>                   
     <markForSuspension>                   
<retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>                 
      </markForSuspension>                    
    <authentication>                     
  <basicAuth>                             
 <username>test</username>       
 <password>test</password>     
   </basicAuth>                    
    </authentication>                 
   </http>           
     </endpoint>         
   </call>      
      <property name="response" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="$ctx:ORIGINAL_MESSAGE"/>     
       <log>             
   <property expression="get-property('response')" name="tt"/>   
         </log>         
   <respond/>     
   </inSequence>    
    <outSequence/>     
   <faultSequence/>   
 </resource>
```

How to handle this issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to do the below? I don't see you have assigned a value to `ORIGINAL_MESSAGE`.

```xml
<property name="response" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="$body"/>
<log>             
   <property expression="get-property('response')" name="tt"/>   
</log>
```

**Update**

Add the following to the `deployment.toml`. Make sure the `content_type` is the same as the Content-Type header that comes in the response.

```ini
[[custom_message_builders]]
class = "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"
content_type = "text/html"
```

Comment: yes this is what i want but it throw exception because the response is HTML format "Unexpected character 'w' (code 119) in start tag Expected a quote at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [5,15]"

Comment: @OussamaNairi check the updated answer.

Comment: Yes ,it works after adding also DISABLE_CHUNKING property after call mediator like this       <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>